# torrc file in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: configuration, tor-install

I installed tor via `brew`:

```
brew install tor
```

I am able to start `tor` from the command line, and the directory that tor is looking for the config file `/usr/local/etc/tor` does not exists after the installation.  I have also looked in the `/usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.1.5_1/` folder tree where the geoIP files are loaded.

I have also looked in several other locations from suggestions on other threads such as:

`~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc`

There is also no log file:

`/usr/local/var/log/tor.log`

```
tor

Sep 21 19:43:22.533 [notice] Tor 0.4.1.5 running on Darwin with Libevent 2.1.11-stable, OpenSSL 1.1.1d, Zlib 1.2.11, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.
Sep 21 19:43:22.533 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 21 19:43:22.533 [notice] Configuration file "/usr/local/etc/tor/torrc" not present, using reasonable defaults.
Sep 21 19:43:22.539 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 21 19:43:22.539 [notice] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 21 19:43:22.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.1.5_1/share/tor/geoip.
Sep 21 19:43:22.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/local/Cellar/tor/0.4.1.5_1/share/tor/geoip6.
Sep 21 19:43:22.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Sep 21 19:43:22.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "default"
Sep 21 19:43:23.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
Sep 21 19:43:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
Sep 21 19:43:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
Sep 21 19:43:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done
Sep 21 19:43:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 20% (onehop_create): Establishing an encrypted directory connection
Sep 21 19:43:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 25% (requesting_status): Asking for networkstatus consensus
Sep 21 19:43:24.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 30% (loading_status): Loading networkstatus consensus
Sep 21 19:43:25.000 [notice] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus.
Sep 21 19:43:25.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 40% (loading_keys): Loading authority key certs
Sep 21 19:43:26.000 [notice] The current consensus has no exit nodes. Tor can only build internal paths, such as paths to onion services.
Sep 21 19:43:26.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 45% (requesting_descriptors): Asking for relay descriptors
Sep 21 19:43:26.000 [notice] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6408, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.)
Sep 21 19:43:26.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 50% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
Sep 21 19:43:29.000 [notice] The current consensus contains exit nodes. Tor can build exit and internal paths.
Sep 21 19:43:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 56% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
Sep 21 19:43:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 63% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
Sep 21 19:43:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 68% (loading_descriptors): Loading relay descriptors
Sep 21 19:43:31.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 75% (enough_dirinfo): Loaded enough directory info to build circuits
Sep 21 19:43:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80% (ap_conn): Connecting to a relay to build circuits
Sep 21 19:43:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85% (ap_conn_done): Connected to a relay to build circuits
Sep 21 19:43:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 89% (ap_handshake): Finishing handshake with a relay to build circuits
Sep 21 19:43:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90% (ap_handshake_done): Handshake finished with a relay to build circuits
Sep 21 19:43:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 95% (circuit_create): Establishing a Tor circuit
Sep 21 19:43:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100% (done): Done
```

Comment: Could you create the missing files/folders? I've experienced that brew not always does what I would expect it to do (partly due to funky permissions in that particular case).

Answer (score 0):

try to find it in the below folder.

```
/usr/local/etc/tor
```

There is a sample file by `torrc.sample` name. You can rename it.